# signed-rank test in R confused

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, self-study, p-value, binomial-distribution

I am self-studying a textbook, and I am confused with the below example.
Could you explain to me how was the p-value calculate using R?

I tried  1- pbinom(x ,y,.5) etc.
I am confused
we have one ( + )
is it x=1 and y=6 ?

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4ehq.png]

I apologize if it is against the rules posting pictures instead of writing the question.

Comment: Just to clarify, what makes you think that `1 - pbinom(15, 21, .5)` would provide the above p-value?

Comment: Maybe it's just me but I find that example quite confusing...

Comment: Maybe it is found by this function wilcox.test(x, y = NULL,
alternative = c("two.sided", "less", "greater"),
mu = 0, paired = FALSE, exact = NULL, correct = TRUE,
conf.int = FALSE, conf.level = 0.95, ...)
wilcox.test(formula, data, subset, na.action, ...)

Comment: As you suggested, it would be better to incorporate the text of this question directly rather than posting the image (that way it's more searchable and more accessible to visually impaired people who use screen readers).  If you need help with formatting, someone can probably step in and fix up your edits if you put the text in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may be mixing up two different tests: 'sign test' and 'Wilcoxon signed-rank test'. (Another possible reason for confusion is that the one-sided test seems to be
looking at the "wrong" tail.)

**Sign tests.** You have six observations from a population with unknown median: $13.9, 10.0, 21.7, 9.3, 5.0, 0.9$ of which only one observation exceeds $16.$
You want to test the null hypothesis $H_0: \eta \le 16$ against the one-sided alternative
$H_a: \eta > 16.$ Your data show most observations below $16,$ so data seem to agree with the null hypothesis. Thus you can expect a large P-value.

Here is output for a sign test from a recent version of Minitab, when data are in C1 of the worksheet.

```
Sign Test for Median: C1 

Sign test of median =  16.00 versus > 16.00

    N  Below  Equal  Above       P  Median
C1  6      5      0      1  0.9844   9.650
```

This agrees with your computation. Under the null hypothesis that the median is $16$ the number of the six observations below 16 distributed $\mathsf{Binom}(n=6, p=1/2),$ so the probability two or more will exceed $16$ is $0.890625.$

```
1 - pbinom(1, 6, .5)
[1] 0.890625
sum(dbinom(2:6, 6, .5))
[1] 0.890625
```

Perhaps it makes more sense to test $H_0: \eta \ge 16$ against $H_a: \eta < 16.$
Then Minitab gives the following output:

```
Sign Test for Median: C1  

Sign test of median =  16.00 versus < 16.00

    N  Below  Equal  Above       P  Median
C1  6      5      0      1  0.1094   9.650
```

Now we could reject $H_a: \eta < 16$ at the 11% level. (The one larger
observations would proved some small doubt about a small population median.)

**Wilcoxon signed-rank test.** Now let's look at a Wilcoxon signed rank test of the null hypothesis that
the population is centered at $16$ (or above) against the alternative tha the
population is centered below $16.$ Minitab output is:

```
Wilcoxon Signed Rank Test: C1 

Test of median = 16.00 versus median < 16.00

       N for   Wilcoxon         Estimated
    N   Test  Statistic      P     Median
C1  6      6        2.0  0.047      9.650
```

And the same test in R gives the following (matching) output:

```
x = c(13.9,10.0,21.7,9.3,5.0,0.9)
wilcox.test(x, mu=16, alt="less")

        Wilcoxon signed rank test

data:  x
V = 2, p-value = 0.04688
alternative hypothesis: true location is less than 16
```

So the null hypothesis is (just barely) rejected at the 5% level.
The sign test has poorer power because it looks only at the *count*
of high observations. The Wilcoxon signed-rank test has better
power because it looks at the *ranks* of the observations, and
observation 21.7 has the highest rank.

```
cbind(x, rank(x))
        x  
[1,] 13.9 5
[2,] 10.0 4
[3,] 21.7 6   # highest rank
[4,]  9.3 3
[5,]  5.0 2
[6,]  0.9 1
```

P-values for Wilcoxon signed-rank tests with small numbers of
observations are taken from a table derived by combinatorics (or
simulation, depending on the software program). For larger numbers
of observations, P-values are obtained by normal approximation.
If you are interested in the details, you can google an explanation
or video that
is at your mathematical level.

---

*Note:* Here are three tests of the null hypothesis that the population
is centered at 25 against the alternative that it is centered above 25,
for samples of size $n = 100$ from $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=26, \sigma = 6),$
so that the null hypothesis is false.

```
set.seed(1030)
y = rnorm(100, 26, 6)
```

Because data are normal a t-test is optimal (smallest P-value):

```
t.test(y, mu=25, alt="greater")

    One Sample t-test

data:  y
t = 1.6809, df = 99, p-value = 0.04796
alternative hypothesis: true mean is greater than 25
95 percent confidence interval:
 25.01393      Inf
sample estimates:
mean of x 
 26.13972
```

A Wilcoxon signed rank loses a little power by looking at ranks
instead of exact numerical values:

```
wilcox.test(y, mu=25, alt="greater")

        Wilcoxon signed rank test with continuity correction

data:  y
V = 2953, p-value = 0.0708
alternative hypothesis: true location is greater than 25
```

A sign test loses even more power by counting the number of values above the hypothetical mean:

```
b = sum(y > 25)
1 - pbinom(b, 100, .5)
[1] 0.09667395
```

Comment: (+1) Nice explanation.